# Get a list of files including this header

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I'd like to search my in c++ code those files including some particular header file.

Something like searching `#include "aHeader.h"` but with a more intelligent search, not a text one.

I don't know if eclipse cdt has this command, and I can't get proper terms for a specific search, all results I got in Stackoverflow and Google were about including files in cdt.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Window -> Show View -> Include Browser`.